# Active record::relation instead of the object's class, when using where method with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to get the attributes of the objects after calling a .where query.  The query is the following:

```
    @matchers = TutoringSession.where(:begin_time_hour => 21).limit(5)
```

I get an array of tutoring sessions as a result.  But I would like to be able to return only specific attributes of each of the matching tutoring sessions.  So I have the following code in my view:

```
    @matchers.each do |matcher|
       matcher.begin_time_hour
    end
```

Instead of listing each of matcher's begin_time_hour attributes, it all of the attributes for each matcher object.  I have experimented with this block trying "puts matchers.begin_time_hour," and have also tried using partials to solve this problem, however I keep running into issues.  If I ask @matcher.class, it says, it is ActiveRecord::Relation object.  I thought it would be a TutoringSession object.

Here are my models, in case this helps.

```
    require 'date'
    class TutoringSession < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :refugee
        belongs_to :student

        before_save :set_day_and_time_available, :set_time_available_hour_and_day

        attr_accessor :begin_time, :book_level, :time_open

        attr_accessible :time_open, :day_open, :tutoring_sessions_attributes,  :page_begin, :begin_time
```

end

and my other class is the following

```
    require 'date'
    require 'digest'

    class Refugee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tutoring_sessions
    has_many :students, :through => :tutoring_sessions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tutoring_sessions, :allow_destroy => true

    attr_accessible :name, :email, :cell_number, :password, :password_confirmation,   :day_open, :time_open, :tutoring_sessions_attributes
```

end

Please let me know if you need more info.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not outputting anything to the view. By calling

```
@matchers.each do |matcher|
   matcher.begin_time_hour
end
```

you get the result from running the loop, which is the relation, instead of the data. You are accessing `begin_time_hour`, but you aren't doing anything with it. You'd need something more like this to display the `begin_time_hour` fields.

```
<% @matcher.each do |matcher| %>
  <%= matcher.begin_time_hour %>
<% end %>
```

By the way, `@matchers` should be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, a representation of the sql query that will be generated from the `where` and `limit` clauses. Calling `all` on the relation with make it an array of `TutoringSession` objects

```
@matchers = TutoringSession.where(:begin_time_hour => 21).limit(5).all
```

Calling `each` implicitly runs the query and iterates over the `TutoringSession` objects, so you shouldn't need to worry about that though.